# checking whether a package is existent or not

Tags: java, reflection

How can i check whether a package like javax.servlet.* exists or not in my installation of java?

Comment: Easy way : Import the package, use it, compile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java can only tell you if it can load a class. It can't tell you if a package exists or not because packages aren't loaded, only classes.

The only way would be by trying to load a class from that package. e.g., For javax.servlet.* you could do:

```
try {
    Class.forName("javax.servlet.Filter");
    return true;
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Check if package is present as a resource:

```
// Null means the package is absent
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("javax/servlet");
```

Alternatively, check if some class of this package can be loaded via `Class.forName(...)`.

Comment: Note that this does not work for JDK 9+, where packages are encapsulated in modules. However, classes are not encapsulated, so the following works: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("java/lang/String.class")`

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the API docs for the installation you have, it will tell you all the installed packages, eg: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/

In code, you can do something like this:

```
Package foo = Package.getPackage("javax.servlet");

if(null != foo){
  foo.toString();
}else{
  System.out.println("Doesn't Exist");
}
```

Comment: This works only if a class was loaded from that package before.

Comment: This will only work if a class from that package has been loaded by the ClassLoader.