# What is com.walkfreestub? (causing crashes on Android)

Tags: android, crash, malware

Quite recently, our Android app has started crashing due to a `NullPointerException` in a package called `com.walkfreestub`. Currently there are absolutely **no** references to this online (we've tried all sorts of other searches related to the crash). Any information about this package or possible causes would be wonderful. Our best guess is that someone has decompiled our APK and modified the original code, in order to re-release it in an unofficial app store.

Notably, this happens most often in India and Nigeria, and frequently on the *Xiaomi 2014818* device (but that might just be a common device in those countries). Versions are mostly Android 4.2 and 4.4, but also a few crashes on 5.1 and others.

**Update:**

There are now several forums online where users are complaining of malware related to `com.walkfree` and `com.walkfreestub`. See links [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117502/walkfree-folder-automatically-created-in-sd-card-and-apks-downloaded-into-it), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-security-discuss/YH80_qADG5E), and [here](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/171034-suspicious-686944448apk-from-mobogenie-allegedly-pou-app/). This unfortunately confirms our hypothesis that the APK has indeed been modified with malware in an unofficial app store.

**Full stack trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: replacement == null
    at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:1348)
    at com.walkfreestub.trace.ReferrerTrack.checkTrackUrl(ReferrerTrack.java:158)
    at com.walkfreestub.internal.PushServiceProxy.startDownloadApp(PushServiceProxy.java:454)
    at com.walkfreestub.internal.PushServiceProxy.notifyToDownload(PushServiceProxy.java:239)
    at com.walkfreestub.internal.PushServiceProxy.notifyMessage(PushServiceProxy.java:274)
    at com.walkfreestub.internal.PushServiceProxy.onMessageLoaded(PushServiceProxy.java:342)
    at com.walkfreestub.internal.push.WalkPushRequest$6.onResponse(WalkPushRequest.java:375)
    at com.walkfreestub.internal.push.WalkPushRequest$6.onResponse(WalkPushRequest.java:1)
    at com.walkfreestub.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    at com.walkfreestub.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:1)
    at com.walkfreestub.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:740)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like some of the classes here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley just cloned and moved namespace

Comment: The `.internal.` classes are called because they are registered `...volley.Response.Listener`s so they are absent from that repo.

Comment: Thanks @weston. We do use Volley in our app, which is probably why this crash is happening. We would like to figure out where this cloned package is coming from so we can determine what to do about it.

Comment: @kevin does this happen only on rooted devices?

Comment: @Guy unfortunately we don't know whether these crashing devices are rooted or not.

Comment: @Kevin I've emailed you through linked in - LMK if you want to go on chat so we can share our finiding and try to hunt this down.

Comment: We also see this exception in one of our apps. The app version which produces this exception is signed with a different certificate. I suspect someone disassembles the app, adds this walkfreestub code and builds it again, and then distributes it outside of Google Play.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Our best theory now is like the one @uwe has mentioned above.

Comment: I think @uwe is on the right track. Googling "com.walkfree" yields a couple of results suggesting it's malware: [1](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/171034-suspicious-686944448apk-from-mobogenie-allegedly-pou-app/) [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-security-discuss/YH80_qADG5E)

Comment: Thank you for the links @SnildDolkow! I searched myself and found a few more. Added links to description.

Comment: I have other reports with different stack traces. Example, one of them starts with: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.walkfreestub.internal.action.WalkActionScanner.resumeDownloadTask(WalkActionScanner.java:178)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages such as `com.walkfree` and `com.walkfreestub` appear to come from a trojan injected into decompiled APKs, distributed through unofficial app stores. The trojan appears to download more unwanted apps in the background, and likely performs other dubious activities. If you come across one of these malicious APKs, please submit it to anti-virus sites such as Malwarebytes!

See similar posts [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117502/walkfree-folder-automatically-created-in-sd-card-and-apks-downloaded-into-it), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-security-discuss/YH80_qADG5E), and [here](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/171034-suspicious-686944448apk-from-mobogenie-allegedly-pou-app/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to detect **com.walkfreestub.*** classes using reflection and notify your user. Most likely, this injections is implemented with automated script so they wouldn't search manually for your detection code.

I mean something like described here [checking whether a package is existent or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547867/checking-whether-a-package-is-existent-or-not)

You check that **com.walkfreestub.*** is present in classpath and notify user that application was compromised by malware and users should be aware of it.

Alternatively, you may try to check APK signature.

Comment: It's unfortunate the app was compromised, but now the responsibility falls on us to ensure our users remain safe. Excellent advice @Olexandr.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened on a Nokia device. I do not use Volley. All HTTP calls are made using OkHttp

The device is apparently rooted and running Android 4.1.2.
Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.xckevin.download.DownloadManager.addDownloadTask(DownloadManager.java:111)
   at com.walkfreestub.internal.download.DownloadControllerForService.download(DownloadControllerForService.java:230)
   at com.walkfreestub.internal.download.DownloadControllerForService.download(DownloadControllerForService.java:201)
   at com.walkfreestub.internal.PushServiceProxy.startDownloadApp(PushServiceProxy.java:435)
   at com.walkfreestub.internal.PushServiceProxy.onActionLoaded(PushServiceProxy.java:525)
   at com.walkfreestub.internal.action.WalkActionRequest$2.onResponse(WalkActionRequest.java:188)
   at com.walkfreestub.internal.action.WalkActionRequest$2.onResponse(WalkActionRequest.java:1)
   at com.walkfreestub.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
   at com.walkfreestub.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:1)
   at com.walkfreestub.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4807)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

It looks like a crash from a 3rd party library which extends Volley.
https://github.com/Houny/Downloader

Comment: Hi @esoxjem, can you please post a crash log or any other information you have? Is something else crashing if you don't use Volley?

Comment: @Kevin Updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Was this of any help?

Comment: I am still getting a lot of crashes because of this.

Comment: Looks like phishing software. Something related to dex spy in the stack trace as well

Comment: Thanks for your comments @esoxjem. Please see the accepted answer for an explanation.