# How to find out whether Spark is installed or not using Java code?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is it possible to check spark installation or spark version through Java Code?

Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: To check for an API, [checking whether a package is existent or not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2547867/4391450)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this might work:`classOf[SparkContext].getPackage.getImplementationVersion` for more information check out [programmatic-way-to-tell-Spark-version](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/programmatic-way-to-tell-Spark-version-td1929.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to check through core java code without using spark code.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** It'd be a very tough programming assignment if possible at all.

You'd have to implement `find`-like Java application to search for files like `jars/spark-core_*-*.jar` and even that would not be an exhaustive search as one could install Spark with a complete rename of everything Spark comes with.

You could also search for some environment variables like `SPARK_HOME`, but since that's not required to use Spark effectively either, I would not count on that.